# How to run cron dynamically in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

I am creating an app in spring boot, which need to implement a complex batch processing task like, there is a table with all the job like below,

```
BATCH_JOBS(id, job, cron_expression) 
row count may be huge but job execution time will be very low.
```

is there any way to implement this processing. Lets say I have @Schedule a method for every 5 minute or 10 minute, when its run will decide which job need to execute according to cron_expression column and split them in thread. Thread will run independently execute the job column and save the result to log. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to look at Quartz http://www.quartz-scheduler.org

Comment: @DonHosek can you please provide documentation of same or any tutorial.

Comment: Follow the link or google quartz scheduler

Comment: thank you very much @DonHosek

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@EnableAsync` and `@Async` annotations for this.
e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfig {
    ...
}
```

then

```
public class ScheduledFixedRateExample {
    @Async
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
    public void scheduleFixedRateTaskAsync() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(
          "Fixed rate task async - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

}
```

Credit: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

You can increase the thread pool size accordingly through additional configuration:

```
package com.example.schedulerdemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;

@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my-scheduled-task-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
}
```

credit: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-task-scheduling-with-scheduled-annotation/

Further example of using `@Async` with cron jobs:
https://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/spring-scheduling-using-annotations/